Error-update on apt/apt-get with link deb-debian-org
I have a problem in my apt Suddenly, when I try to update my apt this problem pops-up every time and I tried a lot of troubleshooting but I still can't figure out why?
$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/129 bookworm InRelease  
Hit:2 https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/129 bookworm Release    
Ign:3 http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Ign:4 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
Err:3 http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Could not connect to archive.debian.org:80 (151.101.194.132). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to archive.debian.org:80 (151.101.2.132). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to archive.debian.org:80 (151.101.66.132). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to archive.debian.org:80 (151.101.130.132). - connect (113: No route to host)
Err:4 http://archive.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to archive.debian.org:http:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.debian.org:80 (151.101.194.132). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to archive.debian.org:80 (151.101.2.132). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to archive.debian.org:80 (151.101.66.132). - connect (113: No route to host) Could not connect to archive.debian.org:80 (151.101.130.132). - connect (113: No route to host)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to archive.debian.org:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


have you tried to ping archive.debian.org ... seems you have a routing issue

Check the Debian Sources: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList . Can you connect? Do you have the correct source?
